# Google Cloud Function: Python and CORS

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, google-cloud-functions, cors

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, I have been reading the Google Cloud Functions documentation but it is not making sense to me...

Here's the link to the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors-python

Here is the code:

```
import flask, json, logging, os, requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

def get_accesstoken():
  try:
    headers   = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    authUrl   = f"{os.environ.get('AUTH_BASE_URI')}{os.environ.get('AUTH_ENDPOINT')}"
    payload   = {'client_id': os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID"), 'client_secret': os.environ.get("CLIENT_SECRET"), 'grant_type': os.environ.get("GRANT_TYPE")}
    resp      = requests.post(authUrl, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

    return resp.json()

  except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    return http_err

  except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
    return err


def addrecord(request): ## <--- this is the entry cloud function
  """HTTP Cloud Function
  Add records to ANY MC DataExtension
  
  Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    data        = request.get_json().get('data', [{}]) // JSON array of objects
    dataId      = request.get_json().get('dataId', None) // string
  """

  request_json  = request.get_json(silent=True)
  token         = get_accesstoken()
  payload       = request_json["data"]
  dextUrl       = f"{os.environ.get('REST_BASE_URI')}{os.environ.get('REST_DE_ENDPOINT')}{request_json['dataExtId']}/rowset"

  # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
  if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
      # Allows GET & POST requests from any origin with the Content-Type
      # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
      headers = {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
          'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
      }

      return ('', 204, headers)

  headers       = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token["access_token"],
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }

  resp          = requests.post(dextUrl, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
  return(resp.raise_for_status(), 200, headers)
```

When I try to send a POST request from my frontend form - I get the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/addrecord' from origin 'https://mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I honestly do not understand what I am missing / doing wrong...I also feel like I may be over complicating things.

To complete the circle, here is the JS code that is doing to POST request:

```
let postData = {...};

$.ajax({
        url: 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/addrecord',
        type: 'post',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        success: function (data) {
          console.info(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        }
      });
```

Comment: Why did my post get a -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't `else` your `if` block that sets the headers.

So your second `headers =` block is always the one that's getting set. The second assignment isn't appending those headers to the data, they're re-assigning the variable entirely. So you're not getting the access origin headers in there.

Way to test it to verify, is to put a `print(headers)` after the second assignment to see what's going on.

Edit: Missing the return in the if block for the OPTIONS case.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - I really appreciate it... ...in the GCP Cloud Function documentation there is no `ELSE` block/statement, which is why I do not have it in my code...

Comment: Notice in the docs though, in the if block, there's a return after the access control headers for the OPTIONS block. Your code doesn't have that return.

Comment: ahhh - true indeed...I think I see what I need to do...

Comment: Awesome! Could you accept the answer so it's easier to search on later? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gabe Weiss --

I realized that I needed to do three things...

First, I added `return ('', 204, headers)` to the end of the `if request.method == 'OPTIONS':` statement.

Second, I moved my request call to after the headers were set.
and Finally, I returned the response